# error occurred when object initialise witin class

Tags: java

```
class Xyz{
    Xyz obj=new Xyz();//becouse of this line i'm geting error why?  

    void m1()
    {
        System.out.println("ffhfhfh");
    }
}

class Abc{
    static Xyz obj1=new Xyz();

    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        obj1.m1();
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: As written, every instance of Xyz will have an obj field of type Xyz. The field is initialized while the enclosing instance is being constructed. You can't do that. Infinite recursion is a bad thing.

Comment: at Xyz.<init>(vvv.java:2) //vvv.java is file name

Comment: can you post anything other than only code?

Comment: Please format the code while posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine that you are getting a stackoverflow error, with a long stack trace pointing to the same line in the code.

When the class Xyz is constructed, it creates an Xyz object, which creates an Xyz object, which creates an Xyz object, ......

Comment: downeyt, you don't need to explain that you've updated your answer, since the edit history is accessible for everyone. :)